# Laravel model returns null sometimes evenif the record exist in the database

Tags: eloquent, mariadb, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have a weird issue. I have a listener runs in queue which is getting a record

`Model::find($id);`

But some times this is returning null even if the record exits in the database, which fails the listener in the queue. If I rerun the failed jobs after sometime, it works without any issue. I can't reproduce it, if I test it manually.

Not sure its a laravel issue or the database(MariaDB) issue!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is activate a log of the query that fails to ensure that everythig is ok:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$model = Model::find($id);
logger ('LOGGED QUERY', DB::getQueryLog());
DB::disableQueryLog();
logger ('LOGGED QUERY DATA', $model?->toArray() ?? []);
```

- Make sure the searched record is not logically deleted (`deleted_at` must be NULL) when you search it the first time.
- You say you're using a listener with a queue - this implies that some action might be running asynchronously, so when you look up the record it's not yet written to the DB. If you use transactions you can set $afterCommit property in your listener class: `public $afterCommit = true;`, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#queued-event-listeners-and-database-transactions) for details

Comment: I put `afterCommit`, added logs onto it. Looks like it is returning null. When I check the record through sql client, it is there. If I reran the failed job after couple of minutes, it will work without any issue.

Comment: I can suppose that some asynchronous action causes the problem.
When is `Model->id` written? Can you give some detail about the action that trigger the listener?